# Change the font size of NSString and loading into text view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, fonts, nsstring

I have a textview that is loading up some text from server in html format. 
But the font size of the text is not changing even if I set it in text view, and its probably because I am currently calculating the textview height based on the text contents from server.

Here are the codes

```
    itemDescribtionView = [[[UIView alloc]init] autorelease];
    [itemDescribtionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [mainPageScrollView addSubview:itemDescribtionView];

    NSString * itemDescribtionStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[delegate.detailPageArray objectAtIndex:delegate.detailArraySelectedIndex]objectForKey:@"item_description"]];


    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                            initWithData: [itemDescribtionStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                                            options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
                                            documentAttributes: nil
                                            error: nil];

    UITextView * itemDescriptionTextView = [[[UITextView alloc]init]autorelease];
    [itemDescriptionTextView setDataDetectorTypes:UIDataDetectorTypeLink];
    [itemDescriptionTextView setDelegate:self];
    [itemDescriptionTextView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:appFontRegular size:18]];
    [itemDescriptionTextView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [itemDescriptionTextView setScrollEnabled:NO];
    [itemDescriptionTextView setEditable:NO];
    [itemDescriptionTextView setAttributedText:attributedString];
    [itemDescriptionTextView setFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,delegate.windowWidth-20,[self heightForAttributedString:attributedString maxWidth:delegate.windowWidth-20])];
    itemDescriptionTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-7.0,0.0,0,0.0);
    [itemDescribtionView addSubview:itemDescriptionTextView];

- (CGFloat)heightForAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)text maxWidth:(CGFloat)maxWidth {

NSStringDrawingOptions options = NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading;
CGSize size = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(maxWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:options  context:nil].size;
NSLog(@"newtext %@",newtext);
NSLog(@"text %@",text);
CGFloat height = size.height + 1; // add 1 point as padding

NSLog(@"%f",height);
if(height<30)
{
    height = 30;
}
return height;
 }
```

I tried to setFont after setFrame in itemDescriptionTextView and it does change the font size, however the height of the textview is not large enough to display all the text.

So I was trying to change the font before the calculation of the height of the textview. But I have no luck so far. And would like to see if anyone can guide me thru. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set the font on attributed string like this before creating the itemDescriptionTextView.

```
[attributedString addAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:appFontRegular size:18]} range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];
```

Comment: it says that 'NSAttributedString' may not respond to 'add attribute:range:'

Comment: `NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData: [result dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes: nil error: nil];`
And then do 
`[attributedString addAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:appFontRegular size:18]} range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];`